# Angular Component with dynamic inputs

Tags: angular, micro-frontend

I want to have a component with dynamic set of inputs and outputs. The component will be able to identify the inputs and outputs it requires at runtime but not when it is coded. This is because it renders micro-components from other projects on request using Module Federation.

Currently I am using a single input and an output which takes all in an object and then pass as required, but this have issues when Angular manages states as changes in an object is not taken as a real change.

[image: Current Implementation]